# Converting XML to Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, xml

Parse XML to array using Javascript

I tried the below code and it worked fine.

```
    var response = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root><node1>something</node1></root>'  

var xmlDoc = $.parseXML( response );

var myArray = getXMLToArray(xmlDoc);

alert(myArray['root']['node1']);
//Pop up window displaying the text "something"

function getXMLToArray(xmlDoc){
    var thisArray = new Array();
    //Check XML doc
    if($(xmlDoc).children().length > 0){
    //Foreach Node found
    $(xmlDoc).children().each(function(){    
        if($(xmlDoc).find(this.nodeName).children().length > 0){
        //If it has children recursively get the inner array
        var NextNode = $(xmlDoc).find(this.nodeName);
        thisArray[this.nodeName] = getXMLToArray(NextNode);
        } else {
        //If not then store the next value to the current array
        thisArray[this.nodeName] = $(xmlDoc).find(this.nodeName).text();
        }
    });
    }
    return thisArray;
}
```

But I am getting Invalid XML error if I pass xml from PHP Curl instead of response variable.

XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<products><product><id>1</id><order_id>100</order_id><product_id>77</product_id><variant_id>40</variant_id><order_pickup_method_id>0</order_pickup_method_id><order_address_id>1</order_address_id><name>[Sample] Fog Linen Chambray Towel - Beige Stripe</name><name_customer>[Sample] Fog Linen Chambray Towel - Beige Stripe</name_customer><name_merchant>[Sample] Fog Linen Chambray Towel - Beige Stripe</name_merchant><sku>SLCTBS-7A4493EA</sku><upc/><type>physical</type><base_price>49.0000</base_price><price_ex_tax>49.0000</price_ex_tax><price_inc_tax>49.0000</price_inc_tax><price_tax>0.0000</price_tax><base_total>49.0000</base_total><total_ex_tax>49.0000</total_ex_tax><total_inc_tax>49.0000</total_inc_tax><total_tax>0.0000</total_tax><weight>1.0000</weight><width>0.0000</width><height>0.0000</height><depth>0.0000</depth><quantity>1</quantity><base_cost_price>0.0000</base_cost_price><cost_price_inc_tax>0.0000</cost_price_inc_tax><cost_price_ex_tax>0.0000</cost_price_ex_tax><cost_price_tax>0.0000</cost_price_tax><is_refunded>false</is_refunded><quantity_refunded>0</quantity_refunded><refund_amount>0.0000</refund_amount><return_id>0</return_id><wrapping_id>0</wrapping_id><wrapping_name/><base_wrapping_cost>0.0000</base_wrapping_cost><wrapping_cost_ex_tax>0.0000</wrapping_cost_ex_tax><wrapping_cost_inc_tax>0.0000</wrapping_cost_inc_tax><wrapping_cost_tax>0.0000</wrapping_cost_tax><wrapping_message/><quantity_shipped>0</quantity_shipped><event_name>NULL</event_name><event_date/><fixed_shipping_cost>0.0000</fixed_shipping_cost><ebay_item_id/><ebay_transaction_id/><option_set_id>NULL</option_set_id><parent_order_product_id>NULL</parent_order_product_id><is_bundled_product>false</is_bundled_product><bin_picking_number/><external_id>NULL</external_id><fulfillment_source/><brand/><gift_certificate_id>NULL</gift_certificate_id><applied_discounts/><product_options><option><id>1</id><option_id>18</option_id><order_product_id>1</order_product_id><product_option_id>108</product_option_id><display_name>Size</display_name><display_name_customer>Size</display_name_customer><display_name_merchant>Size</display_name_merchant><display_value>XL</display_value><display_value_customer>XL</display_value_customer><display_value_merchant>XL</display_value_merchant><value>72</value><type>Multiple choice</type><name>Apparel sizes</name><display_style>Rectangle</display_style></option><option><id>2</id><option_id>3</option_id><order_product_id>1</order_product_id><product_option_id>109</product_option_id><display_name>Color</display_name><display_name_customer>Color</display_name_customer><display_name_merchant>Color</display_name_merchant><display_value>Red</display_value><display_value_customer>Red</display_value_customer><display_value_merchant>Red</display_value_merchant><value>39</value><type>Swatch</type><name>Colors</name><display_style/></option></product_options><configurable_fields/></product></products>
```

Comment: You should show the part that isn't working, instead of the part that is working.

Comment: What's your "xml from PHP Curl"? My guess is it's invalid.

Comment: Something simple like `console.log(response_object_from_PHP);` would likely help clue you in.

Comment: How are you passing from PHP curl to JavaScript? That's probably where the problem is.

Comment: XML attached in the question.pls check.

Comment: It should be something like `var response = <?php echo json_encode($response); ?>;`

Comment: @RekhaAnguraj The XML you "attached" is working for you. What we are suggesting is that that's not exactly what's being returned in your response.

Comment: From PHP , I fetch the response xml thru ajax

Comment: @Marc, I got the xml by using console.log and checked.

Comment: Please post the code that's NOT working, as @James suggested in the first place.